# Extent Report v4 Steps count is updated as 0 in Dashboard

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am using Extent Reports v4 and the steps are not getting updated in Dashboard. But, the steps are recorded under each test perfectly.

Please refer the attachments and kindly suggest if there are any solutions.

[Steps count is updated as 0 in Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk6DX.png)

[Steps are recorded for each step in Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HciMr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this got fixed in 4.1.0 version, please see [the changelog page](http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/#changelog) for more details.

Comment: it's still not fixed in 4.1.0